# How to get the selected DDL value from a row in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, asp.net-identity

right now I am just trying to put together a simple role assigning pages in ASP.NET, I have created a listview, and in my item template I have a drop down list, with a button in the same template. The DDL is hooked up to an ODS which gets me the current roles, and I have a method which will take the role and the username, and assign that user to a specific role. My code is as follows:

```
<h2>Users</h2>
<asp:ListView ID="UserListView" runat="server"
ItemType="Synergy_System.Entities.Security.ApplicationUser"
OnItemCommand="UserListView_ItemCommand">
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>
                No users in this site.
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="AddUsers" Text="Add  users" ID="AddUsersButton" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Item.UserName %>' runat="server" ID="UserNameLabel" /></td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Item.Email %>' runat="server" ID="EmailLabel" /></td>
        <td><em>password is hashed</em></td>

        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="RolesList" runat="server" DataSourceID="RoleListODS" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">
</asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button ID="AddRoleToUser" runat="server" Text="Add Role" onclick="AddRoleToUser_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server">
        <tr runat="server">
            <td runat="server">
                <table runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer"
                    class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <th runat="server">User Name</th>
                        <th runat="server">Email</th>
                        <th runat="server">Password</th>

                        <th runat="server">Roles</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server">
            <td runat="server">
                <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager1">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

I have code behind pretty much empty, as it's just like this right now:

```
protected void AddRoleToUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string username;
string role;
//get username
//get value from DDL



 UserManager.AddUserToRole(username,role);
}
```

I have used GridViews before but haven't dealt with ListViews much. I just want it so that when I click the button in that particular row, i retrieve this information, but there is no .Row in a listview.... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I am not quite sure how to extract the '<%# Item.UserName %>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use `CommandName` property of Button

```
<asp:Button ID="AddRoleToUser"   CommandName="AddRole"
```

Code Behind

```
protected void UserListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "AddRole"))
    {

      ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
      // this will gives you Row for your list items

      Label UserNameLabel=(Label)dataItem.FindControl("UserNameLabel");
    // you can find any control on row like this
      string YourNameLabel=UserNameLabel.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: disregard this, I missed a bracket.

Comment: It seems like it may very well work, I am just hvaing issues right now trying to extract the value from <asp:Label Text='<%# Item.UserName %>' runat="server" ID="UserNameLabel" />